# construct a pushdown automata for L={a^mb^n where n<=m<=2n}?

Tags: automata, computation-theory, pushdown-automaton

I was looking to understand the construction of pushdown automata for `L={a^nb^m where n<=m<=2n}`? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822772/how-to-construct-a-pushdown-automata-for-l-anbm-where-n-m-2n) question on stack over itself.

here is what the answer said which I understood:

> Here's the strategy: we can easily make a PDA that accepts a^n b^n,
> and we can easily make one that accepts a^n b^2n. Our language is a
> superset of these languages that also accepts anything with a number
> of b in between n and 2n. We can make use of nondeterminism to allow
> this as follows: for every a we put onto the stack, we can
> nondeterministically decide whether to consume one or two b before
> popping the a. If our NPDA chooses to consume one each time, we get
> a^n b^n. If it choose to consume two each time, we get a^n b^2n. If it
> chooses some of both, we get a number of b in between these extremes.
> We only accept when we exhaust the input with an empty stack.

Now, I changed the question a little bit(interchanged the powers of a  and b). The language is now `L={a^m b^n where n<=m<=2n}`?
How would this strategy change now if the powers are interchanged?

Comment: How do you think the answer changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We can make use of nondeterminism to allow this as follows: for every a we put onto the stack, we can nondeterministically decide whether to consume one or two b before popping the a.

Just exchange *a*'s and *b*'s in this sentence and you should have your answer.

Hint: instead of putting *a*'s on the stack, you put *b*'s, and then "consume" one or two *a*'s before popping.